# Alter Windows install program

Tags: windows, installation, unzip

I have a *setupOriginal.exe* file, and I would need to update it to had some features.

I can unzip it with 7Zip and it contains a hierarchy like that:

```
Autorun.inf    
setup.exe    
setup.exe.manifest    
Directory\main.msi
```

As far as I know, the file *setupOriginal.exe* is some kind of auto extractable file since I can unzip it.
Once unzipped, I can modify the main.msi file.
But, I am not able to rebuild the packed setup.exe into one file *setupAltered.exe* which would run the same way as before, and contain the hierarchy:

```
Autorun.inf    
setup.exe    
setup.exe.manifest    
Directory\mainAltered.msi
```

I tried:

- to build self extractable with 7Zip and WinZip but there is an intermediate unzip step
- to update setupOriginal.exe inline and save directly without unzipping in WinZip (a new exe is generated, but it is broken) and 7Zip (error message when adding mainAltered.msi "function not implemented")

I guess files are packed with a tool that forward the setup to the inner setup.exe, but I don't know it.
Do I need to use some kind of installer tools (InnoSetup etc.) to wrap the files ? In this case, how could I do it if I just want to pack the files, and run the setup.exe from inside the packed archive (I mean without introducing a intermediate window added by the installer tool itself) ?
Is there any simple way to do that please ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anymore interested, the best approach I found is to use WinZip Self-Extractor program (part of binaries created by WinZip, but different from the main WinZip program I tried to use for SFX, and that will not allow to tune options as far as I know).

You can request for automatic unzipping, set icon and run the inner setup.exe afterwards.
And, finally, it can be called from command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip Self-Extractor\WZIPSE32.EXE" test.zip -setup -t dialog.txt -auto -i icon.ico -c .\setup.exe
```